# Compiling .cs file into dll without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, dll, compilation

How do I compile a `.cs` file to a `.dll` file without using Visual Studio?

Here is an example file:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Test
{
    public class Loader
    {
        public static GameObject load_object;

        public static void Load()
        {
            load_object = new GameObject();
            load_object.AddComponent<GG>();
            UnityEngine.Object.DontDestroyOnLoad(load_object);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fully C#, not C++. This is also a Unity C# file that should be compiled in Unity.

Comment: That was fast, Thanks for the response. Is using MonoDevelop to compile it will work?

Comment: I've never used Unity myself, unfortunately, so I wouldn't know. Wouldn't hurt to give it a try though. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have `.NET Framework` installed, run this command:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\{version}\csc.exe yourfile.cs
```

Of course all dependencies must be in place.

You can find more information about this kind of compilation: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)